# Display default contact photo when no photo assigned?

Tags: android, image, photo, contacts

Here is my code which display the contact photos fine in my listview:

```
 bitmap = loadContactPhoto(getContentResolver(), id);

   if(bitmap!=null){
        favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else{
    }

    String[] from = { ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    int to[] = new int[]{
            R.id.ivDefContact,
            R.id.tvContactName
    };

 public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
    InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);
    if (input == null) {

        return null;
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

}
```

How can I display the default imageView' s resource when no photo is assigned to a contact?

Comment: in the else block of if (bitmap!=null) set the static image to load.

Comment: Can you please give an example? Because I've already tried to do some stuff there and always get nullPointerException. Thanks.

Comment: if(bitmap!=null){
        favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else{
favIcon.setImageDrawable(R.id.yourimg);
    }

Comment: I understood which block you mean, but whatever tried to put there I always get nullPointerException. I just tried to put this: else{
           Resources mResources = ctx.getResources();
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.defcontpic);
           favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }     -> NullPointer exception and points to line Resources mResources = ctx.getResources();

Comment: I just show your complete comment. I already tried this. IDE Error: SetImageDrawable cannot applied to int

Comment: please post your logcat log... that will make things easier to understand.

Comment: or try using favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(bitmap!=null)
{ favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap); }
 else
{ favIcon.setImageDrawable(R.id.yourimg); }
```

This should do it!

place your default image in the drawable folder.

Comment: It doesn't I get  IDE Error: SetImageDrawable cannot applied to int. I already have the image in drawable.

Comment: is favIcon an imageView? if it is so the code should work perfectly! i dont have at other things to say!

Comment: Yes it is, and it displayed fine in listview if I don't include the photos at the contact list. I want to say that there isn't something wrong with the image or the ImageView on xml. I also tried with a default image from android resourses like this: favIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm));   But I'm getting again NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Niraj's, but in my code setImageResource() works better.

```
if(bitmap!=null){
    favIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} else {
    favIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimg);
}
```